# meteor full text search. in client after subscribe, collection contain old search results

Tags: angular, meteor

Im trying to make full text search in meteor with angular 2. there is my publish func:

```js
Meteor.publish("search", (searchValue) => {
    console.log(searchValue);
    if (searchValue) {
        return Nutrition.find(
            {$text: {$search: searchValue}},
            {
                // `fields` is where we can add MongoDB projections. Here we're causing
                // each document published to include a property named `score`, which
                // contains the document's search rank, a numerical value, with more
                // relevant documents having a higher score.
                fields: {
                    'name.long': 1,
                    score: {$meta: "textScore"}
                },
                // This indicates that we wish the publication to be sorted by the
                // `score` property specified in the projection fields above.
                sort: {
                    score: {$meta: "textScore"},
                },
                limit: 20
            }
        );
    } else {
        return Nutrition.find({})
    }
});
```

and in client:

```js
  public searchProducts = _.debounce((query) => {
        Meteor.subscribe('search', query);
        Nutrition.find({}).subscribe(data=>{
            console.log(data.length);
        });
    }, 500);
```

but after each subscribe Collection contain new values (from actual search) and old values (from old searches).

what can be reason of that? And what i can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     Nutrition.find({}).subscribe(data=>{
>         console.log(data.length);
>     });
> ```

This is quite bad: remove it. Call `Nutrition.find({})` inside a Blaze helper or read up on the appropriate ways to bind to data using Angular/React integrations for Meteor.

To address your specific problem, you need to tear down your old subscriptions.

```
var sub = null;
public searchProducts = _.debounce((query) => {
    if (!!sub) {
        sub.stop();
    }
    sub = Meteor.subscribe('search', query);
}
```

This will cause a flickering behavior, which is a different problem. You should extend your `Nutrition.find({})` to filter for some part of your query.

In production settings, I actually create a synthetic field using the publication handle on the server side that indicates which fields are satisfying which query. This may be over-engineered (too challenging to implement correctly) for your needs.

I'd recommend the https://atmospherejs.com/easy/search package.